# How to filter an each loop with nested objects in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-collection2

I am cycling through nested objects in Meteor. I need to be able to filter the nested objects, but i'm not sure how to go about doing that in meteor. Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Here is some example code:

```
People.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name",
        max: 200
    },
    importantFacts: {
      type: [Object],
      optional: true
    },
    "importantFacts.$.year": {
      type: Number,
      index: true
    },
    "importantFacts.$.content": {
      type: String
    }
}));
```

Example of what I am trying to do (does not work):

```
<ul>
    {{#each person.importantFacts.find({ year: 2010 })}}
        <li>{{ content }} - {{ year }}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`{{each}}` is a [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md) looping construct that takes *very* simple expressions. You can'd do `find({...})` in `{{each}}`; you define a template helper, then pass that to `each`:

```js
Template.foo.helpers({
  importantFacts: function () {
    return People.importantFacts.find({ year: 2000 });
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="foo">
  <ul>
    {{#each importantFacts}}
      <li>{{ content }} - {{ year }}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

This separation of concerns is rather basic, so if you've just gotten started with Meteor, it may help to review some of the Meteor basics. [Your First Meteor Application](http://meteortips.com/book/) is an excellent resource. On the other hand, I see you've posted fairly complex Meteor code about a month ago, so maybe I misunderstood your question?